# How to get values from an object have 2 datatype values?

Tags: java, object, iterator

i having a list `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();`

i am getting list of objects if i iterate it i get each object like this when debugging

```
for(Object obj:objects){
   System.out.println(obj);
}
```

I am getting as

```
[0] = Integer -> Value is 2
[1] = Long -> Value is 3

[0] = Integer -> Value is 1
[1] = Long -> Value is 2

[0] = Integer -> Value is 1
[1] = Long -> Value is 4
```

`List<Object> objects = service.getRankings();`

if i iterate the object

```
for(Object obj:objects){
  sysout(obj);
}
```

when i debug the code i will the object with 2 datatype values for each object in the list as

```
[0] = Integer -> Value is 2
[1] = Long -> Value is 3
```

I want the values from the object and set in another object, can anyone help me to get the values from the object?

Comment: what do you want to get? your concern isn't clear. please explain, and correct you last line of question

Comment: List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(); Using object arrayList is a recipe for disasters; I would advice you to provide a specific datatype or a class type for list. Also it's difficult to figure out what you really want, plz elaborate your code a little more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want values from database i suggest the following code:-

First make a Pojo class with variables that relate to existing columns of database.

For example:- Employee table has Employee name and Employee ID

So make a empty java class Employee :-

```
public class Employee {      
   int employee_id;
   String emp_name;
   //setters
   //getters
}
```

Now in your DBManager function getEmployee() :-

```
   public class DBManager {
     //Define Database connection


     public static ArrayList<Employee> getEmployee()
     {
       ArrayList<Employee> list=new Arraylist<Employee>();
       Employee obj=new Employee();
       Prepared statment= con.createPreparedStatment("select * from employee");
       Resultset rs= statment.execute(); // call that execute method which return a resultset
       while(rs.next()) {
          obj.setEmployeeId(rs.getInteger());
          obj.setEmployeeName(rs.getString());
          list.add(obj);
     }
      return list;
    }
```

In your java class get data as follows :-

```
 public class EmployeeExecute {
 public static void main(String args[])
  ArrayList<Employee> ans= DBManager.getEmployee();
   //iterate ans
  }
```

I have given example with Employee Data. Same you can do for your data.

PS:- i have just typed an example so some method name can be wrong.

Comment: i read the comments. Got to know manoj want to get values from database. So changed the ans

Answer (score 0):

public class Test1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer i = new Integer(10);
    Float f = new Float(10.4f);
    Double d = new Double(10.6);

    Object[] objects = { i, f, d };

    for (Object obj : objects) {

        if (obj instanceof Integer) {
            Integer integer = (Integer) obj;
            System.out.println(integer.toString());
        } else if (obj instanceof Float) {
            Float flt = (Float) obj;
            System.out.println(flt.toString());
        }
        if (obj  instanceof  Double) {
            Double dble = (Double) obj;
            System.out.println(dble.toString());
        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: I am getting the object values from the database using normal query like select id, count, rank from tbl_name so that i will get list of objects. so i need to iterate and get the values from the object.

Comment: Below example is not suitable solution for me

Comment: Either explain better or post real code. My answer matches your code.

Comment: Please, please, use `obj instanceof Class` instead of comparing class names. This isn't JavaScript ;-).